# Oozie cannot find workflow file

Tags: hdfs, oozie

File exists in HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://nameservice/user/user123/workflow.xml


-rw-r--r--   3 user123 user123        662 2016-10-24 11:25 hdfs://nameservice/user/user123/workflow.xml
```

Try the same with oozie:

```
oozie validate hdfs://nameservice/user/user123/workflow.xml
```

oozie can't find it:

```
App definition [File does not exist, hdfs://nameservice/user/user123/workflow.xml] does not exist
```

Same error if I try to submit the workflow using oozie run.

What are the possible causes/things to check?

Comment: I think oozie validate can be done if workflow.xml is there in local path

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the local file system path not the HDFS location. This is client side validation.

```
oozie validate <ARGS> : validate a workflow XML file
```